# space showing up between browser window and content

Tags: html

I have got a strange bug happening. There is odd white space showing between the browser window and the body content.

[image]

Comment: Please provide a [MCVE]

Comment: Show your code please.

Comment: By the information you give us to work with it is not ambiguous where the error is - can you post your code please?

Comment: is your file, in the off chance, encoded with UTF-8 BOM?

Comment: The code can be seen on CodePen [link](https://codepen.io/corvine74/pen/dVpLbK)

Comment: This code doesn't help. Try to inspect your html tag and see if it does have some extra padding or margin.

Comment: I already did, the css for the html tag is set to 0 for margin and padding as well

Comment: Your header can have top margin: show the css for the header tag.

Answer (score 0):

What are the style for the html tag?
You need to check the existence of padding styles and margins for the html tag.